# Metrics for weak convergence of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory

For a polish space $(S,d)$ I have see the metric:
$$ \beta(P,Q) := \sup\left\{ \left| \int f dP - \int fdQ \right| \mid \|f\|_{BL} \leq 1 \right\} $$
where $f$ is taken to be Lipschitz and bounded and $\|f\|_{BL}$ is the sum of it's Lipschitz seminorm and it's supremum norm. I know that the space of all probability measures on $(S,d)$ becomes a complete metric space with this metric, but are there some more interesting properties of this metric space? Any references would be appreciated (also just fun facts given in the form of an exercise will be apreciated)!

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most interesting thing is that your metric is equal to the $L_1$ Kantorovich/Wasserstein/transport distance. And there is a lot of research related to this thing (although most of the research is for $L_2$ versions). 
[Wiki1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric), [Wiki2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_%28mathematics%29)

Using right version of the distance you can prove path-connectedness of the space of prob. measures with weak topology, even define a structure of (something like) a smooth manifold there.

Comment: Nice, this is indeed the kind of stuff I was looking for, do you have a reference like a book where these facts are proven?

Comment: I am not ready to give exact references, but I would start looking at one of two huge books about optimal transport by Villani. Probably either it is proven there or there are references to the proofs there. Or maybe it is possible to find it by googling. http://cedricvillani.org/for-mathematicians/surveys-books/